# Question about the group SO(3)

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, lie-groups, lie-algebras

How can I show that any element of SO(3) can be written in the form $ Z_\Phi X_\theta Z_\Psi $ ?

Where, $$ Z_\theta = 
    \begin{pmatrix}
    \cos(\theta) & -\sin(\theta) & 0 \\
    \sin(\theta) & \cos(\theta) & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 1 \\
    \end{pmatrix}  
$$

$$ X_\theta = 
    \begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & \cos(\theta) & -\sin(\theta) \\
    0 & \sin(\theta) & \cos(\theta) \\
    \end{pmatrix}  
$$

Any hints/suggestions will be greatly appreciated ?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort. This should be added to the question rather than in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

Look at any book on classical mechanics, I think this goes under the name of Euler's Theorem and the angles are called Euler Angles.

Basically the idea is the following imagine the sphere with some fixed z direction. Then if I did some $SO(3)$ transformation I'm going to map the sphere back to itself, so let's see what can possibly happen to the sphere. First of all, lets see where the z axis went to under this transformation, it can be anywhere on the sphere so you need two angles to tell me where on the sphere you rotated your z-axis to. Next, even if I know where the z-axis went I can still rotate the sphere keeping the z-axis fixed in its new place, so I need another angle to fix this degree of freedom.

These matrices are sort of carrying out that procedure